# Trying to understand Async/Await but seem to get deadlock c#

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I have an async method, and from within that method I call another Async method.
In the second method I call an API. I know that my API request is correct, so it has something to do with the async/await.

Am I creating a deadlock? If so where? And how to fix it?

```
public async Task<AmountInvoicedModel> CreatePaymentsAndSendAsEmail(InvoiceRequestModel model, bool calculate)
    {
      ....
      await CreateQRCodes("testMsg");
      ....
    }

public async Task CreateQRCodes(string ocrNmbr)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var json = new
        {
            payee = new
            {
                value = "01234567890",
                editable = false
            },
            amount = new
            {
                value = 100,
                editable = false
            },
            message = new
            {
                value = $"{ocrNmbr}",
                editable = false
            },
            format = "jpg",
            size = 300
        };
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "api/v1/prefilled", json);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        

        
    }
```

**UPDATE: I had to put await on the "CalculateInvoice" method too. So now it doesnt deadlock anymore, it moves on - but without giving me a response**

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("calculateInvoice")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CalculateInvoice([FromBody] InvoiceRequestModel model)
    {
        model.EmailAddress = AccountHelper.GetLoggedInUsername();
        var result = await _paymentHandler.CreatePaymentsAndSendAsEmail(model, true);
        if (result == null)
            return Conflict();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;` -> Why don't you `await` it?

Comment: The deadlock is probably caused by `var result = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;` (specifically the use of `.Result`) - change it to `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`

Comment: And at least log your exceptions. Just rethrowing is relatively useless.

Comment: You should also consider _not_ to create a new HttpClient in each call. Have _one_ injected into your class.

Comment: @MartinCostello I changed my code but it just keeps thinking without giving a response. And it seems to be doing that on the postasjson method. Any other ideas?

Comment: @fildor Thank you! I just put the try-catch there quickly to try to see if it would throw an error but it doesnt. It just keeps thinking and never returns a response.

Comment: How frequently have you been trying? I do not _really_ expect port exhaustion already, but who knows ...

Comment: Pretty frequently for the last 2 hours or so. What can I do if it is port exhaustion? @Fildor

Comment: Reboot or wait. But I really don't think it is the problem. Not when testing manually. Is the API (which you are calling) responsive if you try by other means? Like in Postman or cUrl or Fiddler?

Comment: Yes, I even pasted the code for the API-call in the login method just to see, and it works in there! @Fildor

Comment: Is this .NET Framework or is it .NET Core/5/6?

Comment: .Net Framework @Crowcoder

Comment: Make sure to read this: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: You edited the question and replaced the `.Result` with `await`. Did this solved your problem?

Comment: No that didn't solve it, I had to put await on a third method too for it to work (see my updated question) - but something is still wrong because it doesnt give me a response? @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put await on the CalculateInvoice method for it to move on.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("calculateInvoice")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CalculateInvoice([FromBody] InvoiceRequestModel model)
{
    model.EmailAddress = AccountHelper.GetLoggedInUsername();
    var result = await _paymentHandler.CreatePaymentsAndSendAsEmail(model, true);
    if (result == null)
        return Conflict();
    return Ok(result);
}
```